# Node.js - Error caused by a route requiring static export

Tags: node.js

I have a directory structure for my Nodejs server like so (it's been simplified):

```
|-server.js
|-public
  |-static
    |-content
      |-footer.json
      |-header-footer.js
      |-header.json
|-routes
  |-home.js
  |-index.js
```

Relevant /server.js code:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index.js');
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// GET home page
app.get('/', routes.home);
```

Relevant /routes/index.js code:

```
// GET home page
exports.home = require('./home.js');
```

Finally, the relevant /routes/home.js code:

```
var content = require('../static/content/header-footer.js');
```

The server crashes on this final line (the first line of code in /routes/home.js). I've also tried `require(/static/content/header-footer.js)`, `require(../content/header-footer.js)`, and `require(/content/header-footer.js)`; none of which worked.

The error message I receive in my nodejs.log is:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../static/content/header-footer.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/routes/home.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^
```

**Is it possible for a route to require a static javascript export? If so, what am I doing wrong? If not, what could I do differently?**

Additionally, here's my /public/static/content/header-footer.js file just in case:

```
// GET modules
var fs = require('fs');
// Header content
exports.header = fs.readFileSync('./header.json', 'utf8');
exports.header = JSON.parse(exports.header);
// Footer content
exports.footer = fs.readFileSync('./footer.json', 'utf8');
exports.footer = JSON.parse(exports.footer);
```

I'd like to note that the server has ran just fine previous to this big update I've just recently pushed. So while I'm new to Nodejs, I have had it running correctly. If I could just get this trick to work, it would increase the reusability of my code, decrease the code size, and increase maintainability.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

So it seems that changing `var content = require('../static/content/header-footer.js');` to `var content = require('../public/static/content/header-footer.js');` in /routes/home.js did the trick. But I'm curious why the latter works and the former doesn't.

The more detailed directory structure is

```
|-server.js
|-public
  |-static
    |-bootstrap
      |-css
        |-theme
          |-flatly
            |-bootstrap.css
    |-content
      |-footer.json
      |-header-footer.js
      |-header.json
|-routes
  |-home.js
  |-index.js
|-views
  |-layout.jade
```

Where /views/layout.jade has the line:

```
link(href="../static/bootstrap/css/theme/flatly/bootstrap.css", rel="stylesheet")
```

**Updated question:**

**How come require methods in routes need to specify the complete path (i.e., ../public/static/), while references in jade/html do not (i.e., ../static/)?**

This is the source of my confusion. I figure it's the difference between accessing it on the backend of the server versus accessing it on the frontend.

Comment: The issue seems to be the wrong path for the required file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of path, you should add public on it

```
var content = require('../public/static/content/header-footer.js');
```

Comment: This worked. I edited my question to elaborate on my confusion based on your answer. Do you mind affirming/denying my conclusion? Thanks!

Comment: Your conclusion is right, it's the difference between accessing it on the backend of the server versus accessing it on the frontend. You can declare the directory that you want to use for frontend by:         app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));